# How plot non NA values in ggplot as a time series dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have looked around and I can't seem to find a working solution for my specific chart.

I have the following data frame which `dput` output is:

```
structure(list(Dates = structure(c(1392406020, 1392406320, 1392406620
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/New_York"), 
    Values = c(51.846, 44.508, 41.244), Anomalies = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, 62.056)), .Names = c("Dates", "Values", "Anomalies"
), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Data frame for top 6 values**

```
                Dates Values Anomalies
1 2014-02-14 14:27:00 51.846        NA
2 2014-02-14 14:32:00 44.508        NA
3 2014-02-14 14:37:00 41.244        NA
4 2014-02-14 14:42:00 48.568        NA
5 2014-02-14 14:47:00 46.714        NA
6 2014-02-14 14:52:00 44.986        NA
```

It has three columns: Dates, Values, and Anomalies.

Anomalies can be either NA or have a value.

**The problem I'm having is that**

I cannot seem to be able to plot only the non NA values.

**Failed Approach**

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Dates, y = Values)) + geom_line() +
  geom_dotplot(aes(y=Anomalies), colour = "red")
print(p)
```

**Bad Chart**

[image]

**Output I want**

The chart I want will be the one below with a dot on the extreme of the two peaks that are showcasing the anomalies.

[image]

PS. I didn't add the whole dataset, just three rows to showcase a simple use scenarios. My dataset is composed of hundred of records, and I will have at most 10 anomalies.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it:

Replace

```
geom_dotplot(aes(y=Anomalies), colour = "red")
```

For:

```
geom_point(data=df, aes(x=Dates, y=Anomalies), colour="red",size=5, alpha=0.3)
```

**Chart**

[image]

Comment: Could you add an image of the final result so people can see?